# How to show popup at near the given point?

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I have Point.I want to show Popup at near of Point.Is there any property to set it?I found similar questions here,but they arent what i want

Comment: please show a bit more research effort and describe more in detail what your are looking for...

Comment: already there is answer.I said that i have point,and i want to show popup at this point.like intellisense,when caret changes want to replace popup according to caret position

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example. The popup is moved whenever you click the mouse on a window:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication60.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="myWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Grid>
    <Popup x:Name="myPopup" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=myWindow}" Placement="Relative">
      <Label Width="50" Height="20" Background="LightGreen"  MouseLeftButtonDown="Label_MouseLeftButtonDown">I am the Popup</Label>
    </Popup>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  Point current = e.GetPosition(this);
  myPopup.HorizontalOffset = current.X;
  myPopup.VerticalOffset = current.Y;
  myPopup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but can't you just set `Placement="MousePoint"` ?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right about that, I just wanted to show him that via the Offset the popup can be arranged individually on the screen. 
Unfortunately Javidan didn't tell exactly where his "Point" as the Popup startup location is coming from. Thanks for your advice though ...

Comment: i get point from current caret postion and want to show popup under the caret.